# iTunes Store vs App Store (iPhone 4)

Tags: ios

Why are some apps installed via iTunes Store while others via App Store? is there any significance in that? Many thanks.

Comment: Which ones are in iTunes Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confused because on Mac, you access iOS App Store from iTunes, but it is actually iOS App Store. So all your apps are from iOS App Store, not the Mac App Store which is a separate App like iOS App Store is separate on iDevices than iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

No apps are installed via the iTunes Store. The iTunes Store is for music, movies, TV shows, etc. All apps are in the App Store.